# Redirect with data parameter in flask

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

I was trying to learn flask and came across the following problem.This is the example that i was trying to implement.

```
@app.route('/poll', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def poll():
    form = PollForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('details.html', form = form)

    return render_template('poll.html', form=form)
```

But i wanted to have a different url mapping for details.html, for that purpose i created another route as,

```
@app.route('/details/<form>')
def details(): 
   return render_template('details.html', form = form):
```

For using this i have used

```
return redirect(url_for('details', form=form))
```

in poll method inside the if condition. And when i tried to access the same from **detail.html** , i am not able to get it as a object. When tried to replace form with a string, it worked fine. Could you please suggest some mechanism to access form as an object inside the **/details** route ?

**Edit**

I was asking something like this is possible.

```
 @app.route('/poll', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def poll():
        form = PollForm()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
        @app.route('/details')
            return render_template('details.html', form = form)

        return render_template('poll.html', form=form)
```

whenever we get inside the if condition the url will be **/poll/details**.Or is there any
 way to make this kind of **url nesting**, starting from a root url then child urls gets added depending on the business logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot just put a form object into a URL, no. A `redirect()` is a *response*, telling the browser to go load a different URL, the form object is not something you can easily cram into a URL path element.

If you don't need to see a different URL in the browser location bar, don't use a redirect but simply call a different function:

```
def details(form): 
   return render_template('details.html', form = form):

@app.route('/poll', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def poll():
    form = PollForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return details(form)

    return render_template('poll.html', form=form)
```

If you do need a different URL in the browser, then have the `<form>` element post to the `/details` route, not the `/poll` route.

Comment: As you said it worked perfectly. Thanks for the answer. but i was wondering that something like nested URL routing is there in flask.Like in my case the if condition in the /poll can be linked to another route /details. So that the end url looks like /poll/details ?

Comment: @Tony: you can just register `/poll/details`; though I am not sure what exactly you are envisioning here.

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you please check that and suggest me ?

Comment: Nope, still not cleAr what you are trying to achieve. Not that altering your question is the way to go about this; perhaps a chat with people in a chat room is the better approach for that kind of interaction.